# unserialize() PHP error trying to import XML with solspace importer

Tags: solspace, import, solspace-importer

I am running EE 2.7.3 and Solspace Importer 2.2.3. I am getting this error when I select the channel for these entries to go in. I am uploading manually using strict XML.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: unserialize(): Error at offset 11 of 49151 bytes

Filename: importer/mcp.importer.php
Line Number: 1151


Unable to Retrieve Profile Data
```

Here is an example of the XML:

```
<entries>
    <entry>
        <title>Destiny and a Blue Cloak</title>
        <story_author>481</story_author>
        <story_age_rating>PG</story_age_rating>
        <story_excerpt><![CDATA[ Except goes here]]></story_excerpt>
        <story_box><![CDATA[ Content goes here]]></story_box>
        <categories>
            <category>Romance</category>
            <category>Humour</category>
        </categories>
        <status>open</status>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try the "Loose XML" option.
Also run your xml through a validator just to make sure it's clean.

You might also be missing the XML header in your XML file, eg. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Finally, the `<categories></categories>` node should contain a string of category data, such as a comma-separated list of category names.